# jquery document ready if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of jquery that works which you click on a radio button it opens a div. However, on page load the radio button may already be clicked so I would like to have it be open if it is clicked. I would assume I would do the same think below but just change "click" to something else. I cannot figure out exactly what though.

```
$(".static_class").click(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "0") {
        $("#none").show("fast");
    } else {
        $("#none").hide("fast");
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Checking the radio button's state on page load should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($(".static_class").val()==="0")
    $("#none").show("fast"); 
  else $("#none").hide("fast");
}
```

Preferably, you should put your `if` statement in a function, and just call that function on `$(document).ready()` and on `$(".static_class").click()`

Also an option is to allow the server-side script to set the div to either `display: none` if you would not check the radio button or `display: block` if the radio button button would be checked. This would have the div either show or hide before the page is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there *is* `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "0") {
    $("#none").show("fast");
  } else {
    $("#none").hide("fast");
  }
});
```

Your question is a bit hard to understand. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Try just adding `.click()` to the end of your handler assignment to trigger it.

```
$(".static_class").click(function() {
    if( $(this).val() === "0" ) 
        $("#none").show("fast"); 
    else 
        $("#none").hide("fast");
}).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery trigger function
trigger an event after second click that will do it!

Answer (score 0):

As the "value" attribute in the radio button doesn't change, you should use :checked selector instead:

```
$(function() {
  if($(".static_class").is(":checked")) {
    ...
  }
}
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/